# Post information about self learned coding

Tags: discussion

In case I have been searching for a solution on Stack Overflow, but I didn't find it, later I have figured out myself how to do it, isn't it useful for people to see it? is there a way or place or are users allowed to post useful information even if they are not questions in Stack Overflow?

Comment: What's stopping you posting the information in the form of a question and the answer to that question?

Comment: If you feel the question you had is a good fit for the site (ie it's not off-topic, as per the rules in the [help-center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)) you can post a question and [answer it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely!

It is great if you found the solution yourself. And it's also very useful to share this information, it may save the next person with this problem a lot of time.

Just write it as a question-and-answer pair; a self-answered question.

Source: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/